# A paragraph visible when entering a div zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am new at jQuery, and I am trying to do an effect.

The effect consist on a slide in to a visible div. I need the children to be visible when it enters the div, but just the words that are IN the div zone.

Is this possible?

I've been searching for a long time and I have not found anything. 
I attached an example image.
[image: Example image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should first attempt doing this yourself. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and everyone will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `overflow: hidden;` in your CSS.

Here's a guide to the overflow property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

It has examples at the bottom if you're not that used to using CSS